# DXA Model Service & Web Application Caching

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

We are having a strange problem with one of our customer. They are using **SDL Web 8.5** with **DXA Java 2.0**. We have already installed **DXA Model Service 2.2.1** however if they publish components that have links to PDF multimedia items, the PDFs are not available for 10-15 minutes after publishing the main content component. Note that the web application cache is set to 10 minutes.

Sometimes if they re-upload a different PDF (in the same multimedia component) & republish the main component the link still points to the old PDF and even on the presentation server’s file system we can see the old PDF, even if we try to manually access the new PDF’s URL.

Any idea what could be causing this or how do we troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is there any caching enabled in your DXA Model Service?

Comment: Your multimedia pdf, Is that separate multimedia component link field or pdf linked in the rich text?  any case link expansion will be done by model service by default. you can directly hit the modelservice endpoint using postman to see your PageEntity JSON getting the updated pdf URL link or not after publishing, could be a change your web app and modelservice both enabled caching due to scale out the setup it's caching invalidation goes wrong here. Enable Trace in your content service to see what is going on during the publishing.

Comment: @Velmurugan yes we have caching enabled in Model Service as well as DXA web application. Model service is configured to invalidate cache using Apache ActiveMQ based on publish/unpublish. Web app cache is set to 10 minutes.

Comment: @Velmurugan the PDF is a separate multimedia component which is linked in a RTF field.

Comment: DXA in-process model service, there are two caching layers available, one for Tridion Object Caching which is possible to invalidate during the publishing using ActiveMQ but also Modelservice has own caching which is time-based caching, that's why I did ask the first question did you enable DXA modelservice caching?

Comment: @Velmurugan by the other caching you mean the cache settings defined as part of cd_client_conf.xml? If so, yes it is enabled and defined as 10 minutes.

Comment: yes. if you enabled Tridion Object Caching then try to disable all Model Service caching to see still you are getting the issue, In the cd_client_conf.xml  CacheEnabled=false? or Disable caching for the Model Service only and leave CIL caching as is in the  dxa.properties spring.profiles.active=dynamic.navigation.provider,dxa.no-cache

Comment: refer to this sdl documentation https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v10/GUID-500F514A-3411-427B-9D3F-B6771E04959D

Comment: @Velmurugan turning off the model service cache has a noticeable negative impact on the performance of the website.